# SSRS: Insert Blank row after the group

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I am working on a SSRS report which needs to show a blank row after every group. The group by field is "category". The values it takes are "first quarter 2010", second quarter 2010", "first quarter 2011", "second quarter 2011". I want the data in the column as follows:

## Category

First Quarter 2010
Second Quarter 2010

First Quarter 2011

The report gets populated by a sql query. The problem I am having is inserting the blank row after each group.

I have tried to insert a row below inside the group and play around with its visibility property. But have failed. I have also tried to include

UNION NULL, NULL, NULL in my sql query to insert a blank row. BUt since my dataset is huge I am afraid formating in sql will slow the process down .

Please suggest and also let me know if You need more detais. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using the union in your SQL query is the right direction, but you need to use "union all" instead of "union" to keep the database from filtering the result set for unique.  Using union all will just add another row and the performance impact should be inconsequential.